# C++ 2 overloads have similar conversions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing wrapper classes for basic types so they can be typed... except I've run into a problem.  I need both these methods to make it nice:

```
Integer32(FastInteger32 value);
Boolean operator>(Integer32 value);
operator FastInteger32();
```

Except when I go to use the '>' operator between a 'FastInteger' and an 'Integer', the compiler sees two possible routes to go and doesn't just pick one, it blows up.  Is there a way to to tell it to just pick one?

The entire code:

```
typedef unsigned int FastInteger32;

class Integer32
{
public:
    Integer32(FastInteger32 value);
    Boolean operator>(Integer32 value);
    operator FastInteger32();
private:
    FastInteger32 value;
};

int main()
{
    Integer32 a = 5;
    FastInteger32 b = 5;
    if (a < b) { }  // Doesn't know what to do here, convert b to Integer32 and compare or convert a to FastInteger32 and compare
}
```

You guys rock by the way, thanks for helping!

Comment: Integer32 class, which would be the wrapper for the 'FastInteger32', or int

Comment: I'm confused; please post the entire code, especially the piece producing the error. It may well be an error with your constructor.

Comment: Inventing your own `bool` type is almost always a bad idea. `if(a<b)` needs a `bool`, not a `Boolean`. It may work due to a conversion from `Boolean` to `bool`, but if it converts that easily, what's the point of `Boolean` ?

Comment: well mainly to inherit from ReflectableConvertable so collections and such know how to convert it to a reflectable object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ will always prefer an overload which doesn't have a conversion at all. Therefore, adding `bool operator<(FastInteger32, Integer32)` and `bool operator<(Integer32, FastInteger32)` will eliminate all ambiguities.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!  it says too many parameters though and it wont let me do static...

Comment: They should be `static`, they should be in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your constructor (`Integer32(FastInteger32 value);`). Single argument constructors should (nearly) always be declared as `explicit`. Simply change the declaration to `explicit Integer32(FastInteger32 value);`; the definition should not change.

Comment: @RyanBrown Add a `Integer& operator=(FastInteger32 value)`; you should also add a default constructor in this case.

Comment: @RyanBrown On a side note, `Integer32 a = 5` is bad style. It means default constructor a, then assign it 5. It should be optimised out, but it would be better to just `Integer32 a(5)`.

Comment: I tried this to resolve any ambiguities: Integer32& operator=(int value);   and it said 'no suitable constructor exists to convert from int to 'Integer32'

Comment: Defining exact conversion operators helped me fix it so it will work exactly as the base types, but thank you very much for helping!